# Npm running version 2.15.12 instead of the latest version 6 in windows

Tags: reactjs, npm

when i run npx create-react-app my-app i get an Npm version 2.15.12 warning

However when I check node -v i get 14.2.1 and npm -v I get 6.4.1

but when i install my app I get an error / warning.

You are using npm 2.15.12 so the project will be bootstrapped with an old unsupported version of tools.
Please update to npm 6 or higher for a better, fully supported experience.

I have done the following:

1. Uninstalled and reinstalled nodejs
2. deleted the npm_cache  and npm folder from ..AppData\Roaming
3. Deleted npm from ..programmes\node js
4. I have also tried using Windows power shell.

Someone help please.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue and solved it by this command in the Windows PowerShell:

```
npm install npm@7
```

I hope it helps someone as well!

Answer (score 0):

On Windows (non-PowerShell, see below for PowerShell), check which `npm` is being run with `npx` like this:

```
npx where npm
```

Compare the path to `npm` that command returns with this:

```
where npm
```

You may also want to make sure you're not using an old version of `npx` that exists in some surprising place:

```
where npx
```

That will at least allow you to locate the old version of `npm` (and/or `npx`) that you'll want to get rid of.

Additionally, you can force `npx` to use `npm` 6 like this:

```
npx -p npm@6 create-react-app my-app
```

But that will have `npx` install its own `npm` rather than use the `npm` you already have installed, so you'll end up with two `npm` 6 installations on your computer.

For folks on UNIX-like operating systems (or perhaps if you're using WSL), use `which` instead of `where` in the commands above.

In PowerShell, you'll need to use `where.exe` rather than just `where`.

Comment: Where npm and Where npx are working and showing paths without any error. however  npx where npm throws an error and a path to a log file.

Comment: How about `npx where.exe npm`?

Comment: Got the following errors ->

C:\Users\hp>npx where.exe npm
npm ERR! code E404 -
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/where.exe - Not found -
npm ERR! 404  |
npm ERR! 404  'where.exe@latest' is not in the npm registry. -
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!) -
npm ERR! 404 - 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url. - 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-12T21_19_31_086Z-debug.log

Comment: Hmmm... any chance you're using WSL? Does `npx which npm` or `npx command -v npm` show something that's not an error?

Comment: had to reset windows and it worked.  Probably there were conflicting npm / node scripts with other softwares.

Thanks Trott.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from 2022! : I'm using `npm 8.3.0`. It did show the same error. I used a command

> yarn npm info

It finally revealed the path of npm 2.15.12. Deleted those files and I am in real now.

And you need yarn installed.